# Looking for ways to host application in AWS and have it monitored using opensource

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios

I am a newbie in the world of DevOps and have been assigned a task to implement web applications for the customers in AWS and that application monitored (security, metrics and logging) using any of the open source tools. I dabbled with Nagios a little and have gone through the AWS course on security and networking before.

Has anyone done a similar kind of project before? Could anyone share their approach so that it will help me prepare a design document?

Comment: That's super broad, which kind of application ? Are you entitled to modify its code?  What are the goals of this monitoring?

Comment: Why not use the built-in AWS monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

You can try built-in tools that provide by AWS.

AWS calls them **Management Tools**.

[image]
**Amazon Inspector**

> #### Automated security assessment service to help improve the security and compliance of applications deployed on AWS.
>
> Amazon Inspector is an automated security assessment service that helps improve the security and compliance of applications deployed on AWS. Amazon Inspector automatically assesses applications for vulnerabilities or deviations from best practices. After performing an assessment, Amazon Inspector produces a detailed list of security findings prioritized by level of severity. These findings can be reviewed directly or as part of detailed assessment reports which are available via the Amazon Inspector console or API.
>
> [— AWS Inspector](https://aws.amazon.com/inspector/?nc2=h_m1)

**Amazon Web Services (AWS) Monitoring With Nagios**

> Implementing effective Amazon Web Services monitoring with Nagios
> offers the following benefits:
>
> Increased server, services, and application availability Fast
> detection of network outages Fast detection of cloud computing
> environment problems
>
> [— Nagios](https://www.nagios.com/solutions/aws-monitoring/)

Some other tools:

- [Scalr](https://www.scalr.com)
- [Management Tools by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/products/management/)

Comment: Make sure you add *clear* attribution to the sources you use, with direct links to the pages that you take content from. See: [How to reference material written by others](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Use blockquotes (`> content`) to mark text as a quote from somewhere else so it's clear that you didn't write that bit. It's great to use other sites to back up what you're saying; just make sure it's clear that the content is referenced from somewhere else.